is it possible to get a list of URLs from post_content directly in a mysql query via phpadmin?
We have many forms that are hosted externally from our Wordpress environment that we are moving to a different system, so we'd like to generate a list of the pages that contain these links along with the list of links themselves.
From phpmyadmin, I can get the list of pages that include the forms with a simple query like this:
select guid from wp_2_posts where post_content LIKE '%ourformdomain.com%';
Is it possible in the same query to include a concatenated list of the URLs of the embedded forms themselves on each of those pages?  I think I'd want to use GROUP_CONCAT for that, but I'm not sure how the subquery can get the URLs themselves for the page in the query.
I'm hoping to avoid PHP code for this - as it needs to be run in several Wordpress installs.
Thank you for the help.

if you did write PHP code you could do it as a WP CLI command so that you don't have to modify every install, but to do what you're wanting to do technically requires a HTML parser, unless you can phrase what you want as a regular expression, but that's not a WordPress problem that's a generic SQL problem. I don't believe there is anything WordPress knowledge can offer you if you're confining yourself to SQL and can't touch PHP. Also note that a GUID isn't always the URL of the post, or the current URL

Are you asking whether a single query could include a list, e.g. where post_content LIKE 'xxx' OR post_content LIKE 'yyy' ?  Or are you asking if the query result can show you the full URLs used in all posts?  Or is it something else you're looking for?  What do you know and what are you trying determine?

Hi, Dave.  I'm wondering if the query could show the full URL of the links within each post returned in the query.
